# Adding important milestones of a gantt chart

Tags: python, gantt-chart

I have made a Gantt chart but I also want to incorporate payments received milestones on that process Gantt chart itself.
Like they could be just arrows/bars at a particular time with information on how much amount was received.
If possible height would represent % or quantity, it would show details when hovered upon as Gantt chart does too.

```
#gantt chart code
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="A", Start='2022-01-01', Finish='2022-01-15'),
    dict(Task="B", Start='2022-01-05', Finish='2022-02-05'),
    dict(Task="C", Start='2022-01-15', Finish='2022-02-20'),
    dict(Task="D", Start='2022-01-25', Finish='2022-03-05')
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.show()
```

Something like this:

[image]